# SQL Separar consumos por mes completo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo un problema, me gustaría separar el consumo diario por meses completos. Me explico

Tengo una base de datos con clientes, consumo medio diario y fecha de inicio y fin del consumo, estas fechas pueden contener varios meses, os adjunto una imagen para que se entienda mejor

[image: Problem]

Me gustaría separar el consumo por cada mes entre la fecha de inicio y fin como esto

.[image: Result]

Otro problema que tengo és que no puedo usar el EOMONTH por que la version de sql server és antigua

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido user169001 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Que significa separar? ¿quieres filtrar solo los consumos de un determinado mes?

Comment: pega tu codigo de lo que tengas no pongas imagenes

Answer (score 1):

> Otro problema que tengo és que no puedo usar el EOMONTH por que la version de sql server és antigua

Eso no es más que un concepto, porque antigua, solo depende de quien lo mire.

Te voy a proponer una posible solución, pero dado que actualmente no dispongo de ningún sql anterior a 2008, o al menos el nivel de compatibilidad de la base de datos no lo puedo poner a menos, no te aseguro que te funcione.

Para obtener un resultado apropiado, y saber que base de datos tienes, es importante ejecutar SELECT @@VERSION, de donde obtendrás la información necesaria.

```
SELECT S.COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 
FROM SYS.DATABASES S
WHERE NAME LIKE 'LAB1'
/*
compatibility_level
-------------------
100

(1 fila afectada)
*/
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.CLIENTES (CLIENTE INT, MEDIADIARIA DECIMAL(10,2), FECHAINICIO DATE, FECHAFINAL DATE)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.CLIENTES (CLIENTE, MEDIADIARIA, FECHAINICIO, FECHAFINAL)
VALUES
(3,578.67,'20191002','20191016'),
(3,86.94, '20191017','20191217'),
(3,95.97, '20191218','20200213');
GO
```

Como puedes ver, he puesto mi base de datos, con un nivel de compatibilidad de 2008

La primera parte del juego, es que necesitamos que para una diferencia de meses, podamos obtener tantas filas, como meses hay. Existen muchas maneras de hacer esto, pero yo me he decantado por utilizar una magnífica función que ha puesto disponible Itzik Ben-Gan en la web.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- © Itzik Ben-Gan, SolidQ
-- For more, see 5-day Advanced T-SQL Course:
-- http://tsql.solidq.com/t-sql-courses/
----------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNums;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
    L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
    L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
             FROM L5)
  SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n
  FROM Nums
  ORDER BY rownum;
GO
```

Si llamas a esta función te devuelve los números que haya entre el intervalo que le pases (menor,mayor).

```
WITH CTE
     AS (
     --este conjunto no es necesario, pero por si el origen de tus datos fuera otra consulta
     SELECT CLIENTES.CLIENTE
              , CLIENTES.MEDIADIARIA
              , CLIENTES.FECHAINICIO
              , CLIENTES.FECHAFINAL
                FROM dbo.CLIENTES),
     ES_FIN_MES
     AS (SELECT CTE.CLIENTE
              , CTE.MEDIADIARIA
              , CTE.FECHAINICIO
              , CTE.FECHAFINAL
              , DATEDIFF(MONTH, CTE.FECHAINICIO, CTE.FECHAFINAL) + 1 AS MESES
         -- AHORA SABEMOS SI HAY VARIOS MESES
                FROM CTE),
     NUM_ROWS
     AS (SELECT E.CLIENTE
              , E.MEDIADIARIA
              , E.FECHAINICIO
              , E.FECHAFINAL
              , E.MESES
              , FN.n
                FROM ES_FIN_MES AS E
                          CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNums
                     ( 1, E.MESES ) AS FN
         -- UTILIZANDO GETNUMS Tenemos tantas filas como necesitamos (1 por cada mes)            
         ),
     CAMBIAR_FECHAS
     AS (SELECT N.CLIENTE
              , N.MEDIADIARIA
              , N.FECHAINICIO
              , DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, DATEADD(mm, n - 1, N.FECHAINICIO)), 0) AS PRIMER_DIA_MES
              , N.FECHAFINAL
              , DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, DATEADD(mm, n - 3, N.FECHAFINAL)), 0))) AS ULTIMO_DIA_MES
              , N.MESES
              , N.n
                FROM NUM_ROWS AS N
        -- tenemos el primer y ultimo día del més utilizando el desplazamiento.
        )

     select C.CLIENTE
          , MEDIADIARIA
          , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                              CASE
                                  WHEN C.N = 1 THEN C.FECHAINICIO
                                  ELSE CAST(PRIMER_DIA_MES AS DATE)
                              END, 103) AS FECHAINICIO
          , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                              CASE
                                  WHEN C.MESES = 1 THEN C.FECHAFINAL
                                  ELSE CASE
                                           WHEN C.MESES = C.N THEN C.FECHAFINAL
                                           ELSE CAST(ULTIMO_DIA_MES AS DATE)
                                       END
                              END, 103) AS FECHAFINAL
            from CAMBIAR_FECHAS AS C;
```

El primer cte, no sirve para nada, y se podía haber omitido. Lo he expuesto, por si tus datos vienen de otra query, sólo tendrías que incrustarla en el primer cte.

En lo que has puesto como salida esperada, hay un pequeño bug, porque Octubre debería de tener 31/10/2019 y noviembre 30/11/2019

[image: Resultados]

[Funciones de fecha útiles](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/12/15/funciones-de-fecha-para-datetime-utiles/)

[CTE Correlativos](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

[SolidQ GetNums](https://tsql.solidq.com/SourceCodes/GetNums.txt)